# How to sort the received output array?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, sorting

I have to find the scores which are above average and output scores must be SORTED as a LIST and must be in Ascending order.

The code is below

```
#Test scored above avg
def printAboveAvg(arr, a): 
  
    # Find average 
    avg = 0
    for i in range(a): 
        avg = avg + arr[i] 
          
    avg = avg // a 
  
    # Print elements greater than 
    # average 
    for i in range(a): 
        if arr[i] > avg:
            print(arr[i], end = " ")  
# Driver Program 
arr =  [39, 51, 40, 88, 76, 84, 28, 44, 60] 
a = len(arr) 
printAboveAvg(arr, a)
```

Output

```
88 76 84 60
```

Please help me how to sort in list and ascending order

The required output is

```
[60, 76, 84, 88]
```

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sorting.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this. I have modified your script quite a bit, but I think this way is eaiser:

```
def printAboveAvg(arr):

    if len(arr) == 0:
        return

    avg = sum(arr) / len(arr)

    return sorted(i for i in arr if i > avg)

arr = [39, 51, 40, 88, 76, 84, 28, 44, 60]

printAboveAvg(arr)
```

You will get:

```
[60, 76, 84, 88]
```

Comment: Note that your bare `return` in fact returns `None`, which can be problematic as the function normally returns a list, so the calling code would be forced to check the type of your return value. You should either return an empty list or raise an exception, depending on what makes the more sense.

Answer (score 1):

Use `arr.sort()` which will sort your array in ascending order....

Answer (score 1):

Use either of the below before `printAboveAvg(arr, a)`

```
arr.sort()  # Sorts in Ascending order
arr.sort(reverse = True) # Sorts in Descending order
```